# Amplify.configure is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Trying to use AWS `Amplify` with S3 Storage following [this tutorial](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/storage_guide#manual-setup) with the manual set up. I created an `amplify-test.js` file as follows:

```
// import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
var Amplify = require('aws-amplify');

console.log(Amplify)

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
    // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
        identityPoolId: 'my identity pool id', 
    // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        region: 'region', 
    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolId: 'my user pool id',
    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID
        userPoolWebClientId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234', 
    },
    Storage: {
        bucket: 's3 bucket', //REQUIRED -  Amazon S3 bucket
        region: 'XX-XXXX-X', //OPTIONAL -  Amazon service region
    }
});

Amplify.Storage.put('test.txt', 'Hello')
       .then (result => console.log(result))
       .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

But when I run `node amplify-test.js`, I got the following error:

> Amplify.configure({
>           ^
>
> TypeError: Amplify.configure is not a function
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Xiaoyun\VuePwa\aws-cognito-amplify-test\src\amplify-test.js:6:9)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:10)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:238:19)
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:572:3)

I've already installed `aws-amplify` by running `npm install aws-amplify --save`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/443

Answer (score 10):

If you are using `const Amplify = require("aws-amplify")`;

**With**

```
Amplify.default.configure({ Auth: {

  // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
  identityPoolId: 'my identity pool id', 

  // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
  region: 'region', 

  // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
  userPoolId: 'my user pool id',

  // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID
  userPoolWebClientId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234', 
},

Storage: {
  bucket: 's3 bucket', //REQUIRED -  Amazon S3 bucket
  region: 'XX-XXXX-X', //OPTIONAL -  Amazon service region
}

});
```

should solve your problem. It did for me.

Comment: How do I call Auth functions off this?

Comment: @chovy `Amplify.Auth.signIn()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var { Amplify } = require('aws-amplify');
```

Comment: How do I call Auth functions off this?